# How can I enable chat in spectator mode?

Tags: smite

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not seem to open the chat and I couldn't find any option to enable it during the match.

When I spectate a friend's match, is there a way for me to chat with him sending private messages?

Answer (score 2):

As specified elsewhere, there is no way to communicate with a person in another match without private messages or a clan channel. As well, you are spectating on a 3 minute delay; this is to prevent people from influencing the match by spectating (watching team A and warning a friend on team B, for example).

Comment: Yes, but how do you send private messages if you can't open the chat?

Comment: The only way currently is via a third-party application like Skype, Ventrilo, Mumble, Teamspeak, or even conventional messaging apps like AIM or MSN Messenger. Not ideal, I know--but that's how the game is so far.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly noticed, currently, you can not open the chat dialog when spectating. Thus, you can not send text messages to your friend while spectating him.